# Parse Float has a rounding limit? How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, math, parsefloat

I set up a system that parses a compact data string into JSON. I'm using a 19 digit number to store ids. Unfortunately any number greater than 17 digits, `parseFloat()` rounds the last few digits.

This breaks the whole data string. Can I fix this?

For example `8246295522085275215` gets turned into `8246295522085276000`. Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RobertWHurst/mhZ7Q/

Comment: You don't have that many objects, right? Then use regular incrementing IDs starting with `1`. If you want to prevent people from being able to retrieve other objects by changing the ID, add an additional argument containing some random value - then you can still use a proper ID (also in your database as the primary key) and when a user tries to modify the URL he's out of luck since he doesn't know the random string of other items.

Comment: if this is an id why bother treating it as a number at all? just keep it as a string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript has only one numeric type, which is an IEEE 754 double precision [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). That means, you have a maximum of 52 bits of precision, which is a bit more than 15 decimal places.

If you need more precision than that, you have to use a bignum library or work with strings.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers in JavaScript lose precision if they are higher than a certain value.

According to http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference, integers are only reliable up to 15 digits (`9 * 10^15` to be exact).

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these
1. Use a string
2. Split your number in two and save the smaller parts to an array
3. Bignum library
4. Use a smaller number if you can